# pytorch lightning isn't start fit at local environment

Tags: pytorch, nlp, google-colaboratory, pytorch-lightning

I'm study NLP by pytorch.

I have some problem in my local environment.

Same code in Google Colab is work well, but same code in my local isn't work.

This is the code that doesn't work, and output.

I can't find the same problem.

Code using DRAM fully but doesn't show OOM error.

```py
trainer.fit(
    task,
    train_dataloaders= train_dataloader,
    val_dataloaders= val_dataloader
)
```

Error Message:

```
Missing logger folder: d:\lightning_logs
C:\Users\Leecarry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\callbacks\model_checkpoint.py:608: UserWarning: Checkpoint directory D:\ exists and is not empty.
  rank_zero_warn(f"Checkpoint directory {dirpath} exists and is not empty.")
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
C:\Users\Leecarry\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\core\optimizer.py:380: RuntimeWarning: Found unsupported keys in the optimizer configuration: {'scheduler'}
  rank_zero_warn(

  | Name  | Type                          | Params
--------------------------------------------------------
0 | model | BertForSequenceClassification | 108 M 
--------------------------------------------------------
108 M     Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
108 M     Total params
435.680   Total estimated model params size (MB)
Epoch 0:   0%|          | 0/6251 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

[image]

This image is same code in Google Colab.

Please tell me the reason why fit isn't start, and ideas.

I'm so sorry for my English ability.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: How long did you wait? Are your program using CPU at all?

Comment: I waited almost 2 hours. and CPU wasn't used all. and GPU wasn't used all same.